# Can not make an exe file with tkinter and pytorch model

Tags: python, tkinter, pytorch, pyinstaller, exe

I changed .spec file as follows:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
block_cipher = None
excluded_modules = ['torch.distributions'] # add this
a = Analysis(['sample.py'],
             pathex=['path'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn'], # add this
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=excluded_modules, # add this
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

Then run:

```
pyinstaller -F sample.spec
```

Then i got this error:

[image]

**Note:**

- I load the pytorch model from a local .pth file.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this problem? I have exactly the same issue.